# System.Data.DataRowView is selected when i applied a datasource to the DropDownList.....How to get data in it of applied datasource?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

'System.Data.DataRowView' is added in dropdownlist..
If applied data contains 5 records then it appears 5 times in list
help....

Answer (score 0):

Assign the column names of data source to DataTextField and DataValueField of the dropdownlist.

E.g.

```
ddl.DataTextField = "TextColumnName";
ddl.DataValueField = "ValueColumnName";
ddl.DataSource = dt;
ddl.DataBind();
```